# Union of arrays in java

Tags: java

I'm a beginner, I tried to print the union of two arrays i.e Elements present in both the arrays without any duplication.When I tried to print the 3rd array it's giving me different output.I have not yet printed the left out elements (which is 34 in this case).

The output I'm getting is:

Printing while processing `1 4 3 2 22 6`. Printing entire 3rd array after the process yields `1 22 3 2 0 6 0 0 0 0`.

I would like to get the output as follows: `1 4 3 2 22 6 34`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[] array1={1,22,34,4};
    int[] array2={1,4,3,2,22,6};

    int[] array3=new int[array1.length+array2.length];

    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    System.out.println("Printing while processing");
    while(i<array1.length && j<array2.length){
        if(array1[i]<array2[j]){
            array3[i]=array1[i];
            System.out.print(array3[i]+" ");
        i++;
        }
        else if(array2[j]<array1[i]){
            array3[j]=array2[j];
            System.out.print(array3[j]+" ");
            j++;
        }
        else{
            array3[i]=array1[i];
            System.out.print(array3[i]+" ");
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\nPrinting entire 3rd array after the process");
for(int k=0;k<array3.length;k++)
    System.out.print(array3[k]+" ");

   //The left out elements in the rest of the arrays are yet to be printed
}
```

Comment: What do you get? And what do you expect?

Comment: Can you define "union of arrays"? What is the expected result?

Comment: The elements present in both the arrays without any repetition.

Comment: OK, but in which order?

Comment: Printing while processing
1 4 3 2 22 6 
Printing entire 3rd array after the process
1 22 3 2 0 6 0 0 0 0


This is the output im getting. I just want to know why I'm getting different outputs. i mean im printing the same array.

Comment: Also it will be helpful if you tell how to print the left out elements in the rest of the arrays.

Desired output is: 1 4 3 2 22 6 34

Comment: You get 0s at the end simply because you make `max(array1.length, array2.length)` iterations rather than `array1.length + array2.length`

Comment: Voting to reopen, the duplicate is no longer relevant after the edit

Comment: Since I cannot post an answer... `int[] array1 = {1,22,34,4};
int[] array2 = {1,4,3,2,22,6};

Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();

for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) set.add(array1[i]);
for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) set.add(array2[i]);

int[] array3 = new int[set.size()];
Iterator<Integer> it = set.iterator();
int i = 0;
while (it.hasNext()) array3[i++] = it.next();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you are applying a sorted merge algorithm to unsorted data.

The second problem is that you are using `i` and `j`, indexes into the two original arrays, as the index in `array3`, the output. This array should have its own index, say, `k`, which should be separate from the other two.

The third problem is that you stop when you reach the end of any of the two arrays, without finishing the "tail portion" of them:

```
Arrays.sort(array1);
Arrays.sort(array2);
int i=0;
int j=0;
int k=0;
System.out.println("Printing while processing");
while(i<array1.length && j<array2.length){
    if(array1[i]<array2[j]){
        array3[k]=array1[i];
        System.out.print(array3[k]+" ");
        i++;
    } else if(array2[j]<array1[i]){
        array3[k]=array2[j];
        System.out.print(array3[k]+" ");
        j++;
    } else{
        array3[k]=array1[i];
        System.out.print(array3[k]+" ");
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}
// Finish the tail arrays
while (i < array1.length) {
    array3[k]=array1[i];
    System.out.print(array3[k]+" ");
    i++;
    k++;
}
while (j < array2.length) {
    array3[k]=array1[j];
    System.out.print(array3[k]+" ");
    j++;
    k++;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Fkplje)

Comment: I'm still getting different outputs and can you also tell how to print the left out elements?

Comment: @Dici The three-way `if` inside a `while` picking the smallest element leave very little place for a doubt as to OP's intentions. This is an imperfect implementation of the classic ordered merge.

Comment: But look at the desired output, it does not correspond to a sorted merge. Neither do the input.

Comment: @suze Take a look at the edit. Your algorithm assumes sorted input; otherwise you should be looking for duplicates in positions past the current one.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Your code is working fine. Thank you so much. Can you explain why I'm getting duplicates if I didn't sort the input.

Comment: @suze This code can only return a sorted array. Your desired output is not sorted... Next time you ask a question please explain it well

Comment: @Dici Thanks for the tip. Much appreciated.

Comment: @suze Unless the data is sorted, you cannot look at one number from each side at a time. Let's say you have `1, 2, 3` and `5, 6, 1`. Your `i` and `j` are both at zero, so you compare `1` to `6`, and decide to write `1`. However, there is another `1` at the end of the second array, which your algorithm will no longer see.

Comment: Now I see. Thank you very much @dasblinkenlight.

Answer (score 1):

[System.arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) was developed to do that...

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)   {
int[] array1 = { 1, 22, 34, 4 };
int[] array2 = { 1, 4, 3, 2, 22, 6 };
int[] array3 = new int[array1.length + array2.length];

System.arraycopy(array1, 0, array3, 0, array1.length);
System.arraycopy(array2, 0, array3, array1.length, array2.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array3));
}
```

EDIT: using java8 we can remove the repeated elements.

```
int[] result = Arrays.stream(array3).distinct().toArray();
```

Comment: I'm trying to find union without any pre defined functions.

Comment: Why not a union without using Java ? That'd be awesome ! Seriously, I dislike questions with stupid requirements. If the language provides something for your use-case, why not using it ?

Comment: you just copied the elements of 1st two arrays into the 3rd array. I asked for union of arrays which means all the elements without any repetitions.

Comment: I'm not the answerer. Plus, since your question is not clearly stating the desired output it's no wonder the answer is not to your taste. Anyway, if you want to remove duplicates just use a `Set`. If you want to keep the order use a `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: This code is not doing what OP wants to do - he's going for a set-like union operation of two sorted arrays, i.e. skipping duplicates (see his last "else" for the reason why I think this is what he wants to do).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, if we read carefully the question again, we will find NO REFERENCE to allowing or not duplicates....

Comment: Even before the edit confirming that he wants no duplicates OP has supplied enough code to make it clear what he's doing. The loop with a three-way conditional has a distinct signature of an ordered merge algorithm, even though the implementation is imperfect.

Comment: Could you guys vote to reopen as the duplicate is no longer relevant ? Cheers